# How to save date in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

i am new to html and php. i am trying to calculate difference between two dates. although i have managed to make a JS function for calculation the difference. but it need two date variables to calculate the difference.

i have use   `<input type="date">` to make an input of date from user. but now the problem i am facing is that how can i store the vale in the textbox(the date in it) into a variable ?
is there any `$_POST` method to get the date stored into a variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an event Javascript and pass the new value parameter.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="date" name="dateOne" value="" onChange="setDate(this.value);"/>
```

**Javascript**:

```
var date;
function setDate(val) {
    date = val;
}
```

**Edit** (based on comment)

For set the variable into a form, create an input type hidden (or other).

```
<input id="jsValue" type="hidden" name="jsValue" value="" />
```

In Javascript put the value into your input

```
document.getElementById("jsValue").value = yourVariable;
```

To see a result in your web page, create a span tag (or other)

```
<span id="seeYourVariable"></span>
```

In Javascript use the property innerHtml to put your variable into the tag

```
document.getElementById("seeYourVariable").innerHTML = yourVariable;
```

Comment: i am little confused in how to use js variables in html ?

Comment: use [innerHtml](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) for use js variable in html

Comment: can you please show me how to do that ? 
as i am new and do not have any idea about innerhtml. like the example you have given above

Comment: i describe two ways to pass a js var into html

Answer (score 1):

Use a hidden field to store the value of the variable and you will get the value using $_POST.